# Adapting An Encryption Algorithm Written in Javascript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, hmac, hmacsha1

To summarize my problem, I want to adapt an encryption algorithm written in Javascript to the Java side. The content produced here is used in the header of the service I am calling. But even though I have tried many ways, I have not been able to find the real algorithm yet.

The algorithm written in Javascript is as follows:

```
function doFunction() {
    apiSecret = "ZDhhODhlOTI2ZjFmNGQ5MDlhMzg5Y2JhZTQyOGUzNDY=";
    date = (new Date()).toUTCString();
    signatureContentString = 'date: ' + date;
    signatureString = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signatureContentString, apiSecret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    authHeader = encodeURIComponent(signatureString);
    alert(authHeader);
}
```

The algorithm I tried on the Java side is as follows:

```
public String createCredential(){
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.RFC1123_PATTERN);
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate);
    String signatureContentString = "date: "+date;
    byte[] bytes = HmacUtils.hmacSha1(Constants.apiSecret, signatureContentString);
    byte[] encode = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
    String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(encode.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return  encoded;
}
```

Example output when I try it on the javascript side:

```
rJxRUgl1%2Bxj5UZSC9rZAHxSl7fw%3D
```

Example output when I try it on the Java side:

```
%5BB%4079c7ad7f
```

The formats do not match each other.
By the way, if you need the RFC1123_PATTERN constant;

```
public static final String RFC1123_PATTERN = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`encode.toString()` returns a String representing the `byte[]`, s. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/9014097), but not, as you probably assume, an ASCII or UTF8 decoding.

For the latter use in the Java code:

```java
byte[] encode = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(new String(encode, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

or alternatively:

```java
String encode = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(encode, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Test:
For the date string `Sat, 18 Jun 2022 17:07:55 GMT` both codes return the value `rSQNB1HOmHEPH982kd9ix0%2F%2F58A%3D`.

Comment: I tried it now and it works flawlessly, thank you very much.